# Search not returning expected results

Tags: support, search

I was just looking for a specific question that I had just looked at. Google history failed me this time but I knew enough about the questions and answers to search for it. Here's my search:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vagrant+ansible+localhost+shell+%5Bansible%5D

Here's the question that I was looking for:

[Running tasks on localhost with Vagrant and Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320691/running-tasks-on-localhost-with-vagrant-and-ansible)

There are only 11 results from that search and my question isn't one of them even though it's tagged with "ansible" and has three of the search words in its title.

Removing "shell" from the query does return it as the first result but it should definitely be in the results even with "shell".

Why didn't my search return the question that I was looking for and how can Stack Exchange fix it so that it does?

Answer (score 2):

The way *our* search works is that *all* keywords have to appear in order for it to match. We don't search on combinations of keywords like Google does. The word "shell" does not appear in the question, so it does not match your keyword set with it included.

Comment: That's an answer to why it did not return but doesn't really answer how this can be fixed. The search should definitely be expanded to answers as they are arguably more valuable that the questions themselves.